# Declaration of Laminas\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface::get($name) must be compatible with Psr\Container\ContainerInterface::get(string $id)

Tags: magento2.3, laminas

Magento 2.3.5-p1 having issue Declaration of Laminas\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface::get($name) must be compatible with Psr\Container\ContainerInterface::get(string $id) /var/www/html/vendor/laminas/laminas-servicemanager/src/ServiceLocatorInterface.php on line 16

Please provide the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem when installing Adobe Commerce 2.4.5. I had this line in one of the php ini files:

```
opcache.file_cache=/tmp
```

After removing it, the problem went away.

Considering that `vendor/laminas/laminas-servicemanager/src/autoload.php` declares `\Interop\Container\Containerinterface` to be an alias of `\Psr\Container\ContainerInterface`, this error must mean that the a.m. autoload file is not being loaded for some reason.